# How to Integrate babun shell in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, babun

I have tried changing the settings for `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` to `babun mintty` location. But the babun shell window opens separately and doesn't integrate with the VS code. Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

After trying for 2 hours finally made it work.

Before reading my way of doing this, you might want to got through [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24588) first.

By default `babun` is installed in `C:\Users\13000\.babun\`. So we can configure it by overriding user setting in `VS Code` as:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\.babun\\cygwin\\bin\\zsh.exe",
```

After saving , reload the window and you are done.

You will get something like :[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: The solution is not working I am receiving following error:
`The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221225477`

Comment: I got this to work, but  with one weirdness: why is there a '%' above each prompt ?
<BR/>%
<BR/>{ ~ }  »                                                                                                                <BR/>~
%
{ ~ }  » l

Comment: Why does this site not allow comments to be edited after 5 min - and even then tell us only after we hit save ?? Just disable the darn edit button !

Comment: Nm, fixed it from another post just use "unsetopt PROMPT_SP" https://superuser.com/questions/645599/why-is-a-percent-sign-appearing-before-each-prompt-on-zsh-in-windows

Comment: @PiKey by default directory being home you mean the path for shell when opened is home or install directory is home? :)

Comment: I mean like opening a terminal in VS Code, instead of being opened at project path it is always home

Comment: @PiKey oh, then that can be changed with `"terminal.integrated.cwd": "",` setting present under settings. For more information you can visit : https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings . Good luck !

Comment: vs code https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.vscode-terminal-here worked great with babun

Answer (score 4):

I was searching for any solution for this issue before and I could not find any. But I was curious how **Babun** itself run the command "**Open Babun here**" from right-click menu and noticed it runs this command:

```
C:\Users\YOURUSER\.babun\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe /bin/env CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/zsh.exe
```

I've tried setting `mintty.exe` as **shell** and using leading commands as **shell arguments**, but this method opens an external terminal. I've noticed this behavior is because using `mintty.exe`, so I replaced `mintty.exe` with `env.exe` itself. At last, these are the settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\YOURUSER\\.babun\\cygwin\\bin\\env.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
  "CHERE_INVOKING=1",
  "/bin/zsh.exe"
]
```

**Edit**: This might not completely relate to this question, but because of having the similarity, I think it might worth mentioning.

During my search for a solution, I've seen many other questions about the same issue for integrating **Atom's PlatformIO IDE Terminal package** or **JetBrain's IDEs** with **Babun's zsh**.

In the case of **Atom**, setting the **Shell Override** to `C:\Users\YOURUSER\.babun\cygwin\bin\env.exe` and **Shell Arguments** to `CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/zsh.exe` opens `zsh.exe` as an integrated terminal in the project directory.

In the case of JetBrain, I've used **WebStrom** and this works:

```
cmd.exe "/k C:\Users\ehsan\.babun\cygwin\bin\env.exe CHERE_INVOKING=1 /bin/zsh.exe"
```

Comment: This is the best answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nonoroazoro I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing the correct answer that `Pramesh Bajracharya` gave above, you can override user settings in VS Code `opening the VS Code` and going in:

```
File->Preferences->Settings
```

And then paste in the field shown in your right side (`WORKSPACE SETTINGS`):

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Users\\YOURUSER\\.babun\\cygwin\\bin\\zsh.exe"
}
```

More information can be found in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

*Thanks Pramesh Bajracharya!*

Comment: I'm glad this helped. Happy coding :)

Comment: How is this any different from what the accepted answer was ?