# How to set mintty.exe as the default terminal on Windows?

Tags: visual-studio-code, mintty

I am trying to set the https://github.com/mintty/mintty terminal installed by `Cygwin` as the default Visual Studio Code terminal with:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\Cygwin\\bin\\mintty.exe",
```

But it opens the `Mintty.exe` terminal on a new window, instead of show it as an embedded console.

---

Related thread I found about it:

1. [How to change the integrated terminal in visual studio code or VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487445/how-to-change-the-integrated-terminal-in-visual-studio-code-or-vscode)
2. [How to Integrate babun shell in VS code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44107919/how-to-integrate-babun-shell-in-vs-code)
3. [Is it possible to configure Babun/ZSH for the integrated terminal on Windows?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24588)
4. [How to integrate terminal whth babun on windows?](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10373)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use "D:\\Cygwin\\bin\\bash.exe" instead of mintty

cheers.

Comment: This changes the shell, not the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

There are two terminal settings, you may want set them like this:

```
"terminal.external.windowsExec": "D:\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe",
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "D:\\cygwin64\\bin\\bash.exe",
```